# Windows 10 popups text out of proportion?

Tags: windows-10, visualization

I just received a new laptop (preinstalled Windows 10) and it behaves weird in the sense that some popups (not all...!) are out of proportion when it comes to text.

[image]

An example below. Note the "normal" size Visual Studio, and the huge R# popup. Please note that the applications Visual Studio and R# are completely irrelevant in this matter (it also happened with default windows popups).

- I have no "Ease of access" settings enabled.
- I have no "show larger texts" (just 100%) in display settings.

Any ideas how to get rid of this rather annoying feature?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Display settings:

Settings > System> Display 
-OR- right-click the desktop and choose Display Settings

2. Adjust the slider under “Change the size of text, apps, and other items.”
3. Click the “Advanced display settings” link at the bottom of this page
4. Select the “set a custom scaling level”